# Как отследить нажатие на иконку поиска search view?

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

Использую `SearchView` из библиотеки `android.widget`:

```
    final SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            Message.showMessage(searchView.getContext(),"test");
            return false;
        }
        });
```

`Message.showMessage` это мой аналог стандартного Toast для вывода тестового сообщения.

Не могу понять, какой метод отвечает за прослушивания события нажатия на кнопку лупы на виртуальной клавиатуре?

[image: Скриншот эмулятора устройства с клавиатурой]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно установить слушатель изменения ввода в `SearchView` так:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
        //вызовется при нажатии на лупу на клавиатуре
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
        //вызовется при изменении ведённого текста
        return true;
    }
});
```